# OneClick Publish "Application validation did not succeed"

Tags: c#, orleans

When publishing my Orleans silo project I keep getting this error (when I try to install the published files), I have tried the following:

- Setting the properties to "Create application without manifest"
- Disable "Enable ClickOnce security settings"
- Remove the refference to "OrleansCounterControl.exe" it then gave the same exact error but with "Orleans.dll" instead.
- I have restarted the project, reinstalled the dependencies, restarted the computer, and rebuild the projects.

I have found a lot of projects describing this with error with references to their other projects, but I am having a hard time finding anything with NuGet Packages giving this issue.

This is the first application I have ever tried to publish in VS, so it can be a simple thing I don't know about.

In debug mode it compiles and everything works without errors.

I have shown the error message I get when I try to install my published program below.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
clr.dll             : 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : file:///C:/SHMSSilo/SHMSSilo.application
Application url         : file:///C:/SHMSSilo/Application%20Files/SHMSSilo_1_0_0_12/SHMSSilo.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : SHMSSilo.application, Version=1.0.0.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
Application Identity        : SHMSSilo.exe, Version=1.0.0.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\SHMSSilo\SHMSSilo.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly OrleansCounterControl.exe.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [23-01-2018 11:29:49] : Activation of C:\SHMSSilo\SHMSSilo.application has started.
* [23-01-2018 11:29:49] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [23-01-2018 11:29:49] : Installation of the application has started.
* [23-01-2018 11:29:49] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
* [23-01-2018 11:29:52] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
* [23-01-2018 11:29:52] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [23-01-2018 11:29:52] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
    - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly OrleansCounterControl.exe.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Your entry point is SHMSSilo.exe, Could you please check "Create application without manifest" flag for SHMSSilo.exe and OrleansCounterControl.exe assemplies. Also for 100% insure check your *.exe assemblies, they must haven't embedded manifest text  [Example](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2aY-F70K6dg/WQDcNU2mH8I/AAAAAAAAArs/MWUDfxJ23WEtywYH8KWN2bDWfQNFZRfnwCLcB/s640/Pic1.png "(It must be non-existing)")

Comment: I can see that the [setup.exe](https://imgur.com/l27mEtS) has a manifest in it, and the [OrleansCounterController](https://imgur.com/rzVK9Vn) but I don't understand how I am supposed to create application without manifest for a nuget package.

Comment: You need to use [mt.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375649(v=vs.85).aspx). As me know it let you work with assembly manifest, pls try to google "mt exe remove manifest"

Comment: setup.exe out of check. Try to remove it from executable assembly

Comment: Hmm removing manifests in the published files, just gives me hash errors. I don't think messing with the published files will ever be a more permanent solution.

Comment: Sorry if i said something incorrect, but you actions must be removing manifest from OrleansCounterController and republish with unpdated assembly. Please try it and let me know. I had a same problem. Thanks

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes I just misunderstood what you were writing, I tried removing the manifest from the published files (which did not work). Removing the manifest from the packages before using publish worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following Sergey Vaulin's advice and removed manifests from the NuGet packages that were giving problems.

I found a tool called "Anolis Resourcer" which can remove manifests from executables. Removing the manifests from OrleansCounterControl.exe and OrleansHost.exe